# Установка прозрачности нескольких объектов Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать остальные объекты на сцене прозрачными или размытыми при вызове картинки?

То есть, как панель проигрыша. Ты ее вызываешь, и на ней как бы фокусируется камера, делая остальной фон размытым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Найдите заблюренную картинку (желательно белую, с прозрачностью) и наложите ее между нужным вам объектом и всеми остальными. Изображение, можете взять на подобии [этого](https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/white-blurred-background_1034-249.jpg), поиграв с его прозрачностью в настройках юнити. Пожалуй, самый дешевый в плане производительности и низкий в плане качества вариант.
2. Можете глянуть [официальный урок](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/post-processing-effects-motion-blur-2019-3#5f49e6d8edbc2a29443e1c00) от юнити на тему Motion Blur, это похоже на то, о чем вы спрашиваете. Реализуют посредством пост-эффекта (что дороговато на мобильных устройствах).
3. На английском SO есть [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188747/how-to-create-blur-effect-to-all-the-scene-except-for-one-object-focus-on-that), в точности как ваш, с подробнейшим ответом. В этом решении предлагается использовать пост-эффект, что достаточно дорогое удовольствие, особенно на мобильных устройствах (может сильно повлиять на производительность).

Comment: Спасибо, как раз хотел первым способом воспользоваться

Comment: то что он хочет это скорее не моушин блюр, а Gaussian Blur. Но это достаточно дорогое удовольствие в плане производительности.